# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error on websocket connection

Tags: java, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I'm trying to connect to my websocket from a different domain. 
The server is on localhost:8098 and the client is on localhost:8080.
Everytime i try to connect i get a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error, i also added the `.setAllowedOrigins("*")`.

Not sure what's missing.

Server

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class webSocketObjects implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws/Object").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();


    }
```

Client

```
<script>
    let stompClient=null;
    import Stomp from 'stompjs';
    import SockJS from 'sockjs-client'
    export default {
        name: "modal",
        props: ['node'],
        data() {
            return{
                bacnetObject: '',
                status: "disconnected"


        }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.bacnetObject = this.node;
        },
        methods: {
            connect: function(){
                const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8098/ws/Object');
                stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
                stompClient.connect({
                }, function (frame) {
                    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/user', console.log(String.body))

                })
    },
            disconnect: function () {
                stompClient.disconnect();
            }
    }
    }
</script>
```

Error I am getting:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8098/ws/Object/info?t=1571728150435' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using credentials, `*` would not work according to the documentation at MDN. Try to specify the host instead.

> For requests without credentials, the literal value "*" can be specified, as a wildcard; the value tells browsers to allow requesting code from any origin to access the resource. Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials will result in an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

On the other hand, sometimes depending on your case, you may need to take care of these headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: header1, header2 ...
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests